# Access REST API in spring ends in 404 error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am currently building a REST API in spring. However, I am failing with a simple sample application. I have already read many articles and have tried a lot. Unfortunately without success...

I think the problem with this is that the RestController is not found automatically.

project structure:

[image]

RestdemoApplication (main):

```
package rest.restdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestdemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

RestingController (RestController):

```
package rest.restdemo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RestingController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

What I have already tried:

- ComponentScan
- changing basePackages and basePackageClasses
- with Configure and CommandLineRunner
- Beans
- GetMapping
- RestdemoApplication (main) defined as RestController (worked here!)

Comment: please share application.yml or application.properties file content and also your configuration file

Comment: application.properties file is empty and in pom.xml i use the spring-boot-starter-web which is generated by Spring Initializr.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x or 3.x ? Maven or Gradle ?

Comment: Spring Boot version 3 with Maven

Answer (score 0):

I test your code like the one below and get an answer

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

does your project have any context path?

Comment: I don't think so that my project has a context path. application.properties is empty and if I define RestdemoApplication (main) as RestController it's working with localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Thx for your code. I have tested it but unfortunately it does not work either. I have also already tried it with ResponseBody.